# No Results in Scope query(Build Search Query displaying no results)

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, solr, content-search

I am adding scope into site under tenant in Sitecore 9.3, When I build a query in `Build Search Query`, it always shows 0 results. I also inherited templates from **_Searchable** template.

[image]

Indexes were also added under `Site Grouping`.

[image]

Solr service is working fine when checked in Solr admin panel.
Also tried rebuilding indexes, from the Sitecore launchpad, in configurations, and indexing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you check the search logs to see the query that is performed when you try the scope? That is the best place to start.

Comment: Checked search logs, but the file is empty

Comment: I would try to fix that first.. you'll need that information.

Comment: No logs releated to search query created in Search Log file

Comment: It doesn't look like you have you created different indexes. Just try removing that indexes setting. It is useful for customization.  https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12680/is-there-a-way-to-define-index-per-site-in-sxa